# How do I replace the default url/path REST helpers in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, helper

```
resources :cimgs, :path => :pics, :as => :pics

match '/enviar'     => 'cimgs#new',         as: 'new_pic'
```

When I call new_pic_path I keep getting /pics/new instead of /enviar

How should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might change order cause routes are matched from the top or add `:except` option to the resources part

```
resources :cimgs, :path => :pics, :as => :pics, :except => :new
```

Answer (score 1):

write the below code above like:

```
match '/enviar'     => 'cimgs#new',         as: 'new_pic'
resources :cimgs, :path => :pics, :as => :pics
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can write `match '/enviar'     => 'cimgs#new',         as: 'new_pic'` above `resources :cimgs, :path => :pics, :as => :pics`; second - read this: [Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)